# Have a single row of a table row cover the whole document

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a single row of a table cover the whole document.
To be more precise, I only need that "fake `<hr>`" to be a specific plain color (no content, no text, etc.).

What would be the simplest way to achieve that using CSS?
Please note that modifying the HTML source is hard because:

- the table is generated through a JSP page which makes use of Struts Layout, second
- many pages are affected, and I cannot afford to modify them all

I have quickly tested having a `<hr>` tag inside a cell, but it does not seem to cover the whole screen, it is limited to the table width, which does make sense.

I am working with HTML 4.01 and CSS3 (CSS 2.1 would be better 'though).

EDIT: to rephrase, what I needed was to have a tr have an arbitrary size (superior to the other rows size). The solution has been given below (thanks !) and is absolute positionning.

Comment: I just learned about this earlier today, but could width:100vw and height: 100vh work?  I'm not fully educated on it yet though.  More info: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Comment: im sorry, im not understanding what the desired result is. would you be able to clarify what is the end result you would like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding width: 99vw to your HR tag (I believe this is CSS3):

```
    <div style="width: 50%; background: #aaa;margin: 0 auto;">
        <table>
           <tr>
             <td> 
                hi 
                <hr style="width: 99vw;left: 0; position: absolute;" />
                there
             </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f6p2j8rf/)

Comment: Position: absolute can have an impact on size (also mentionned in CSS 2.1 reference, this is an oversight on my part), which is making it working here. Your sample makes exactly what I wanted.
Thanks !